# Ember.js: How to remove folders (.svn) from asset compilation

Tags: svn, ember.js, ember-cli

I am using Ember.js with ember-font-awesome. For some reasons I have to version control my project with svn what puts a .svn folder within every directory. When building the project, ember automatically compiles assets (uglify, minify, copy to appropriate directory). This works for assets within dependencies as ember-font-awesonme out of the box. Buit it fails when having a .svn folder within the ember-font-awesonme fonts directory.
This is the error message: 
`You must pass a file to 'app.import'. For directories specify them to the constructor under the`trees`option.` First I really don't know where and how to specify directories to the constructor (maybe somehow in the `ember-cli-build.js`) ansd more important, I don't want to specify it to the constructor. Insteasd I want to exclude it from compilation process.

Would be very fine if someone had a solution for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be happier with an svg icon sprite like fontastic.me - muy bueno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secondly - if you don't import files from ember-font-awesome directly using app.import calls in your ember-cli-build file then you could try using specific options in configuration for ember-font-awesome in ember-cli-build. For example you can switch off including assets:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  'ember-font-awesome': {
    includeFontAwesomeAssets: false
  }
});
```

or font files:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  'ember-font-awesome': {
    includeFontFiles: false
  }
});
```

You could definitely switch off automatic font imports and import them directly in your CSS.

So, if experimenting with configuration of addon could help you but... It's possible that ember-font-awesome passes whole directory to app.import call and .svn directory (under fonts) is recursively picked. If this is true, then you would need probably to fork addon and do changes that suits you by yourself. However switching off automatic font import and importing them manually should help you.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's always good to know where to do configuration settings. In my particular case the solution was much more simple: using an up-to-date version of svn (1.9 and above) did the job because these versions do not put .svn folders in every directory but only in the root directory. So the problem is solved. Unfortunately my svn-client didn't support latest svn versions so I had to take another one.